# SICP - exercise 2.20 - same-parity

Tags: performance, beginner, lisp, scheme, sicp

> Exercise 2.20.  
> The procedures +, *, and list take arbitrary numbers of arguments. One way to define such procedures is to use define with dotted-tail notation. In a procedure
> definition, a parameter list that has a dot before the last parameter name indicates that, when the procedure is called, the initial parameters (if any)
> will have as values the initial arguments, as usual, but the final parameter's value will be a list of any remaining arguments. For instance, given the
> definition
>
> (define (f x y . z) )
>
> the procedure f can be called with two or more arguments. If we evaluate
>
> (f 1 2 3 4 5 6)
>
> then in the body of f, x will be 1, y will be 2, and z will be the list (3 4 5 6). Given the definition
>
> (define (g . w) )
>
> the procedure g can be called with zero or more arguments. If we evaluate
>
> (g 1 2 3 4 5 6)
>
> then in the body of g, w will be the list (1 2 3 4 5 6).
>
> Use this notation to write a procedure same-parity that takes one or more integers and returns a list of all the arguments that have the same even-odd
> parity as the first argument. For example,
>
> (same-parity 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
> (1 3 5 7)
>
> (same-parity 2 3 4 5 6 7)
> (2 4 6)

[source](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.1)

Please review my code.

I have implemented a helper procedure, called predmap (Note: I am not aware of (filter) before writing this exercise). It's identical to map, but the function argument is a predicate. The item will be added in the new list if the predicate is true.

```
(define (predmap pred lst)
    (if (null? lst) '()
        (let ((carst (car lst))
            (next (predmap pred (cdr lst))))
            (if (pred carst)
                (cons carst next)
                next))))
```

Here is the same-parity procedure:

```
(define (same-parity . lst)
    (if (null? lst) '()
        (cons
            (car lst)
            (predmap (if (even? (car lst)) even? (lambda (x) (not (even? x))))
            (cdr lst)))))
```

In the second argument to cons, I put the if statement in the function argument directly to avoid repeating the call to predmap in the code. But it seems to look complicated now.

How can I make this code better and faster? Is there a better solution? Perhaps one where we would not need procedures like predmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to determine the parity of a whole number is calculate the modulus of the number wrt 2:

```
(modulo 4 2) => 0 (even)
(modulo 5 2) => 1 (odd)
```

Your `predmap` is useful however it's a reinvention of a wheel. The standard function `filter` does the same thing.

So you could write the solution as:

```
(define (same-parity xs)
  (let ((parity (modulo (car xs) 2)))
    (cons (car xs) 
          (filter (lambda (x) (= (modulo x 2) parity))
                  (cdr xs)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: my Lisp is extremely rusty.

- `same-parity` must have at least one argument, so the proper declaration would be `(same-parity arg . rest)`.
- A more natural predicate for determining same parity of `x,y` is `(even? (- x y))`
- A more natural helper is `(same-parity-helper arg lst)`. Notice the absence of dot: it can recurse.
- Putting it all together,

  ```
      (define (same-parity-helper arg lst)
          (if (null? lst) '()
              (cons
                  (if (even? (- arg (car lst))
                      (car lst))
                      '())
                  (same-parity-helper arg (cdr lst)))))

      (define (same-parity arg . rest)
          (same-parity-helper arg rest))
  ```